# Converting timestamps from a csv to seconds using python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have sensor data(acclerometer,compass) saved in a csv file with their time stamps hh-mm-ss format. I wanted to convert the time stamp into seconds to plot the compass reading at a particular second.
ex:
I want to convert

```
11-26-32 -> 0 sec
11-26-33 -> 1 sec
11-26-34 -> 2 sec
```

.
.
.
so that i can plot the readings with the seconds on x axis and the compass orientations on y axis.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the times to `datetime` objects and use the difference of the `datetime` objects from the initial time to find the number of seconds. `total_seconds` returns the number of seconds for the `timedelta`:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

times = ['11-26-32', '11-26-33', '11-26-34']
time_format = '%H-%M-%S'

base_time = dt.strptime(times[0], time_format)
seconds  = [(dt.strptime(t, time_format)- base_time).total_seconds() for t in times]
print(seconds)
# [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```

I assume the years, months and days of the timestamps are all the same since they were not provided.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas solution:

assuming that you have the following CSV file:

```
Time,val
11-26-32,11
11-26-33,31
11-26-34,33
11-26-35,10
11-26-39,7
```

**Solution:**

```
import pandas as pd

In [225]: filename = r'C:\Temp\.data\a.csv'

In [226]: df = pd.read_csv(filename)

In [227]: df
Out[227]:
       Time  val
0  11-26-32   11
1  11-26-33   31
2  11-26-34   33
3  11-26-35   10
4  11-26-39    7

In [228]: df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%H-%M-%S')

In [229]: df['sec'] = (df.Time - df.ix[0, 'Time']).dt.seconds

In [230]: df
Out[230]:
                 Time  val  sec
0 1900-01-01 11:26:32   11    0
1 1900-01-01 11:26:33   31    1
2 1900-01-01 11:26:34   33    2
3 1900-01-01 11:26:35   10    3
4 1900-01-01 11:26:39    7    7
```

now let's plot it:

```
In [235]: df.set_index('sec').plot()
Out[235]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x808e2b0>
```

[image]